# Firefox Add-on Builder print all tab titles

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to write a Firefox Add-on. But at the moment I'm stuck at the very beginning. :/
I found this example Add-on somewhere on the web:

```
console.log("test");
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
for each (var tab in tabs)
  console.log(tab.title);
```

When I install it, it only prints the following lines to Browser-Console:

```
[15:56:18.096] "XPI delayed ... try to load every 2 seconds"
[15:56:19.097] "installing from /xpi/test/2djt52m26cni8/"
[15:56:20.098] "request is running"
[15:56:21.081] "test"
[15:56:20.949] "Editor blurred, forcing resize of renderer."
[15:56:21.229] "Add-on installed"
[15:56:42.761] "Editor blurred, forcing resize of renderer."
```

"Editor blurred, forcing resize of renderer." is this a bad message?
Well, however, the Add-on does not print the tab names or anything besites "test". So what am I dogin wrong? Why does my Add-on think that there are 0 tabs?

I'm using builder.addons.mozilla.org to create and test the Add-on btw. I just cleared the main.js and pasted the code from above.

Update:
The output of this: http://pastebin.com/3BrX7qQb is:
"test"
0

Comment: Replacing console.error by console.log gives you the same result ?

Comment: yes, i used console.log the beginning and then I tried to use console.error instead. The result was the same... I'm pretty sure now that console.log() is fine. The problem must be that my Add-on thinks that there are 0 tabs. I'm gonna edit the post...

Comment: Try tabs.length to check if your add-on detects 0 tabs

Comment: console.log(tabs.length); returns 0

Comment: Looks like you're using the add-on builder website? What version of Firefox do you use?

Comment: Yes I'm using forums.mozilla.org to build the Add-on. My Firefox version is: 25.0.1

Comment: The editor blurred is nothing to worry about. There's nothing wrong with the code. There must be something wrong with the setup. It works fine for me. What version of the sdk are you using?